# Ubuntu 14.04 multi user rdp with active directory authentication

Tags: unity, remote-desktop

I have never tried this and hopefully I am missing some basic concept of vital piece of information, I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 Server and I have downloaded likewise to enable active directory authentication which is all working well - the last thing I need to do is enable remote access to about 20 people who are familiar with Unity Desktop environment - there seems to be no supported way of doing this for a 3d environment either on unity or gnome - I have seen some workarounds using xrdp and a 2d desktop environment 'xfce' - while I got this to work it is not accepted as a solution - can anyone point me to a solution to enabling remote access with multi-user support and 3d desktop environment - I am open to any suggestion except team viewer or anything like it.

EDIT: rdp will be initiated from Windows 7 clients.

many thanks,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

I would have added a comment instead of an answer but due to lack of points can't do that! Anyways, this is what I had to add: If remote desktop is all you want then why not go with VNC? I had slight difficulty initially but got it working, steps documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556358/desktop-sharing-on-14-10).